# Function to calculate a gradient using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, math, optimization, statistics

I am trying to write a function to calculate a gradient in R. The function must specifically do so using a for loop. I am writing this function in order to illustrate how a for loop is less efficient than vectorized programming when trying to calculate the gradient.

The function takes in a design matrix X and a vector of coefficients beta in order to calculate the gradient of a cost function (The design matrix is a matrix of covariates with ones on the first column.)

The cost function is the MSE,

[image]

. I am calculating the gradient using an analytical solution, taking the partial derivative of the loss function. This gives us the partial derivative as ,

[image]

for the first coefficient $\beta_{0}$  and then similarly for all other coefficients $\beta_{j}$,

[image]

I managed to calculate the answer (implementing the above) using vectorized programming as the line of code below.

```
-2*t(X)%*%(y-X%*%beta)
```

My attempt at using a for loop, does not work but it looked like this,

```
  # Initialize the matrix to hold gradient
  gradient = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(beta))
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(beta)){
    
    if(i == 1){
      gradient[i] = -2*sum(y - X%*%beta) # first value
    }else if(i>1){
      gradient[i] = -2*sum( t(X)%*%(y - X%*%beta) ) * apply(X[,-1],2,sum)[i-1]  
    } }
```

Below is the code to generate data to use and the two implementations that I tried in R. The code generates the data and can be used to test fixing the for loop if copied into R.

```
# Values
# Random data Generated
n = 4  
p = 3

beta_0  = 2
beta = matrix(c(beta_0,3,1,4), nrow= (p+1) ) # coefficients
X = runif(n=(n*p), min=-5,max= 5) # covariates
X  = matrix(X, nrow = n, ncol = p)
X = cbind(1, X) # make a design matrix
y = apply(X[,-1],1,mean)  # Response (Some function) # 

# Print all to show all initial values 
print(list("Initial Values:"="","n:"=n," p:" = p, "beta_0:" = beta_0," beta:"=beta,
           " X:"=X," y:" = y))



#             Function 1
# Find the gradient (using a for loop)
# The partial derivative of the loss function
df_ols = function(beta,X,y){
  
  begin.time <- proc.time() 
  # Initialize the matrix to hold gradient
  gradient = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(beta))
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(beta)){
    
    if(i == 1){
      gradient[i] = -2*sum(y - X%*%beta) # first value
    }else if(i>1){
      gradient[i] = -2*sum( t(X)%*%(y - X%*%beta) ) * apply(X[,-1],2,sum)[i-1]  
    } }
  
  end.time <- proc.time()
  time <- (end.time-begin.time)[3]
  
  print(list("gradient 1"=gradient,"time"=time))
}

df_ols(beta,X,y)

# Function 2
# Find the gradient Approach 2 using vectorized programming
gradient_3 <- function(X, beta){
  
  begin.time <- proc.time()
  
  # Finding the gradient
  grad_3 <- -2*t(X)%*%(y-X%*%beta)
  grad_3 <- matrix(grad_3, ncol = 1,nrow = ncol(X)) # Turn into a column matrix
  end.time <- proc.time()
  
  time <- (end.time-begin.time)[3]
  
  print(list("gradient 3"= grad_3 ,"time"=time))
  
}

gradient_3(X, beta) # Assumed Correct
```

I apologize if I was not too wordy. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the for loop to work, below you'll see the answer.

```
# Find the gradient (using a for loop) explicit, element-wise formulations 
# The partial derivative of the loss function
df_ols = function(beta,X,y){

  begin.time <- proc.time() 
  # Initialize the matrix to hold gradient
  gradient = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(beta))

  for(i in 1:nrow(beta)){

    if(i == 1){
      gradient[i] = -2*sum(y - X%*%beta) # first value
    }else if(i>1){
      gradient[i]   =  -2*t(X[,i])%*%(y-X%*%beta)
      #gradient[i] = -2*sum( t(X)%*%(y - X%*%beta) ) * apply(X[,-1],2,sum)[i-1]  
    } }

  end.time <- proc.time()
  time <- (end.time-begin.time)[3]

  print(list("gradient 1"=gradient,"time"=time))
}

df_ols(beta,X,y)
```

, running both the vectorized and elementwise formations we find the vectorized process is much faster. We implement the full process below.

```
# Random data Generated
n = 100000*12  
p = 3

beta_0  = 2
beta = matrix(c(beta_0,3,1,4), nrow= (p+1) ) # coefficients
X = runif(n=(n*p), min=-5,max= 5) # covariates
X  = matrix(X, nrow = n, ncol = p)
X = cbind(1, X) # make a design matrix
y = apply(X[,-1],1,mean)  # Response (Some function) 

# Print parameters. To show all initial values 
print(list("Initial Values:" = '',"n:"=n," p:" = p, "beta_0:" = beta_0," beta:"=beta,
           " X:"=round(X,digits=2)," y:" = round(y,digits=2)))


# Function 3
# Find the gradient Approach 3, using vectorized programming
gradient_3 <- function(X, beta,y){

  begin.time <- proc.time()

  # Find the partial derivative of the rest (j'th)
  grad_3 <- -2*t(X)%*%(y-X%*%beta)
  grad_3 <- matrix(grad_3, ncol = 1,nrow = ncol(X)) # Turn into a column matrix
  end.time <- proc.time()

  time <- (end.time-begin.time)[3]

  print(list("gradient 3"= grad_3 ,"time"=time))
}
```

Showing the results

```
> df_ols(beta,X,y) # Elementwise
$`gradient 1`
         [,1]
[1,]  4804829
[2,] 53311879
[3,] 13471077
[4,] 73259191

$time
elapsed 
   3.59 
> gradient_3(X, beta,y) # Vectorized Programming solution
$`gradient 3`
         [,1]
[1,]  4804829
[2,] 53311879
[3,] 13471077
[4,] 73259191

$time
elapsed 
   0.89
```